# How do I resolve the "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" issue when trying to use the rmsprop optimizer?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Here is my code for the neural network I'm trying to get up:

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models
from keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_dir = 'C:/Users/BaskaranBadr/Documents/Deep Learning/cats_and_dogs_small/train'
validation_dir = 'C:/Users/BaskaranBadr/Documents/Deep Learning/cats_and_dogs_small/validation'

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape = (150,150,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape = (150,150,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape = (150,150,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape = (150,150,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='binarycrossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.rmsprop_v2(lr=0.0001), metrics = ['acc'])
```

The error I keep getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\BaskaranBadr\Documents\Deep Learning\CatDogClassifier.py", line 24, in <module>
    model.compile(loss='binarycrossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.rmsprop_v2(lr=0.0001), metrics = ['acc'])
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

`rmsprop_v2` is just an alias for `rmsprop` module inside `optimizers` package (see [keras on GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/1b5a05fceef4fd2e3b87352f00c4a9b2effd46f9/keras/optimizers.py#L39)).
You shouldn't use this alias. Just

```
from keras import optimizers
```

and then

```
opt = optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='binarycrossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics = ['acc'])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I'm running into a different problem after implementing what you suggested. I am getting the following message:
  
opt = optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001)
AttributeError: module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'RMSprop'

Comment: Can you make `from keras.optimizers import RMSprop` and then `opt = RMSprop(lr=0.001)`? If no wich version of Keras you use? And Keras as separate package or as subpackage of TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `rmsprop_v2` is exist or not, or it is `rmsprop` of `keras.optimizer_v2`, you can check this [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L39) of `keras`.
If you want use `RMSprop`, you can follow this way:

```
import tensorflow as tf

optim = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='binarycrossentropy', optimizer=optim, metrics = ['acc'])
```

Comment: @Badri Baskaran used `keras` library, not `tf.keras`. We mustn't mix both them in one code due to versions incompatibility problems. But i'd prefer `tf.keras`.

Comment: Hi, my problem got solved. Thank you all!

Answer (score -1):

To access Keras in Tensorflow 1, use 'import keras'. Most older code and tutorials need their imports rewritten as 'from tensorflow.keras import X' when using Tensorflow 2.

Use:

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
```

Comment: both previously given answers already say essentially that. you're just changing the words of the import around.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The first answer is importing from keras when it was its own package, rather than part of tensorflow. Point of my answer is some people need to rewrite their old keras imports to use tensorflow, as that was a depreciated way to access keras. This is one of the differences between Tensorflow 1 and Tensorflow 2. I should have been more explicit.